# In Google Sheets, analyze cell content, and if certain values are present, return a response in the next column

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, regex

In the below example, I want to analyze each cell in column `A`, and if the cell's contents match certain parameters, return a value in column `B` accordingly.
So if the value in a col `A` cell = apple, banana or pineapple, it should return a value of `Fruit` in col `B` for that item.
Or if the value of a cell in col `A` = truck or motorcycle, it should return `Vehicle` in col `B`.

Haven't been able to figure this one out

[image: ell]

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se] . Please add a brief descrition of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following formula

```
=ArrayFormula(IFNA(IFS(REGEXMATCH(A2:A,"Banana| pineapple|Apple")=true,"Fruit", 
                        REGEXMATCH(A2:A,"Truck|Motorcycle")=true,"Vehicle")))
```

[image]

Functions used:

- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`IFNA`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9365944)
- [`IFS`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7014145)
- [`REGEXMATCH`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292)

Comment: Welcome. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: Do you know why it's only returning the expected values in B2-3 and not B4-9? (screenshot here: https://imgur.com/a/DBTl3RE). Also - is it true that I'm not able to manually edit any of the cells in column B now without stopping the formula? What I'd ideally looking to do is run a formula over a long column, have it return values for the applicable scenarios I code, and then for the cells that don't have an applicable automated answer, fill those in manually.

Comment: Also, I should have specified I'm looking to have match word (apple or banana, etc) just be included in the cell being reviewed - NOT exactly match. I.e. "Green Apple" or "Apple" or "Apples" would all return "Fruit".

Comment: Have you tried the given solution? Did it work for you? If not we should try finding out why. If yes, as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and maybe [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: I did, but haven't received responses to my notes about trying the above

Comment: *"Do you know why it's only returning the expected values in B2-3 and not B4-9?"* The reason being you should NOT have any spaces between the words as in`Banana|Pineapple|Apple` or `Truck|Motorcycle`. Also *"is it true that I'm not able to manually edit any of the cells in column B..."*. **Yes**

Comment: *"I should have specified I'm looking to have match..."* This is a completely different thing. I would suggest accepting this answer and creating a new question as well as reading how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler (but less scaleable) alternative would be to use IF(OR(<"string1";<"string2";);(;))

So, in your target cell (D4 in this case) type the following formula:

```
=IF(OR(A4="truck";"motorcycle");"vehicle")
```

Comment: When I tried this formula, it worked on the first cell, but gave the error seen here (https://imgur.com/a/iEFnDBG) for the rest... I'm looking to have a formula consider multiple criteria at once for a long column of data. If it's an apple or banana, it's a fruit, but if it's a truck or car or motorcycle, it's a vehicle, or if it's a pen or pencil, it's a writing instrument. Also - I should have specified I'm looking to have match word (apple or banana, etc) just be included in the cell being reviewed - NOT exactly match. I.e. "Green Apple" or "Apple" or "Apples" would all return "Fruit".

Comment: you could expand the function to use Find https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094126?hl=en